# PWA: Address bar showing up when redirectioning to subdomains

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA that uses subdomains sometimes. The problem that I found happens when app redirects to another subdomain: Address bar shows up. This affects app-like experience.

Someone knows a solution to hide address bar when using subdomains?

[image: app screen]

Comment: I'd **guess** that this (showing the address when you change origins) is a security feature to prevent phishing attacks and that there will be nothing you can do about it other than *not using different subdomains*.

Comment: Is there a way to validate different subdomains? It is not redirecting to a different domain, I understand the security question but I guess the redirect keeps the same environment (domain).

Comment: You can try to add "Service-Worker-Allowed" header in ServiceWorker response. https://medium.com/dev-channel/two-http-headers-related-to-service-workers-you-never-may-have-heard-of-c8862f76cc60

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar issue when redirecting to subdomains. The address bar normally shows up when the PWA is not correctly set-up to behave like an app. In my case, the `manifest.json` was not loading properly after redirecting.

This link may also prove useful - [Chrome PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a blog post about this

1. https://blog.hackages.io/migrating-a-service-worker-from-an-old-domain-to-your-new-domain-69236418051c
2. https://github.com/0xClpz/migrating-service-workers-from-an-old-domain

It's an older post, and I have not been able to replicate their results in 2020 on Chrome 81 Android 10

Imagine you need to migrate your app from `old-domain.com` to `new-domain.com`

You do 301 redirects for SEO reasons. All good, everything works, for new users, and users who didn't install the pwa to home screen.

When you try to open the old installed pwa, it sees the redirect to `new-domain.com`. This is what triggers the address bar. It opens a new window within the pwa, because the domain is different. Just as if you were in some native app and tried to login via facebook or github.

The installed pwa never tries to load `sw.js`, it just goes for the redirect, not giving you a chance to intercept anything.

---

For new users, when they visit `new-domain.com` it offers them the usual pwa add to home screen prompt.

If by some chance, some new user visits `old-domain.com`, they get redirected to `new-domain.com` and are offered the pwa experience from `new-domain.com`

---

I'm not sure what the solution can look like.

I've been thinking about detecting server side if the request came of old installed pwa, and showing them some crafted page, instructing them to remove the old pwa from their homescreen, and then visiting the new domain...