# iOS 13 PWA URL bar shows up when navigating to a new page

Tags: safari, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA (specifically concerned about iOS Safari at the moment), where when I add the PWA to my homescreen, the page I was on when I added it shows up like a native app. However, when I navigate within the PWA (same domain just new pages) the URL bar shows up.

This post was similar, but mentions it's for chrome/android.
[PWA: Address bar showing up when redirectioning to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580434/pwa-address-bar-showing-up-when-redirectioning-to-subdomains) -- and, as I understand it, iOS doesn't use all of the manifest file. I tried setting the scope, but no luck.

I have the necessary head elements in for showing a standalone (like I said, the initial page when I saved the PWA to the homescreen works fine).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by undoing the router mode `history` and reverted back to `#` hash-based routing.

I'm using Vue, so basically I just **undo** what I did here
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html